# In SFMC, see who was suppressed from a send

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

This question feels a little silly, but I haven't had any luck with it on my own, and Support has been useless. I'm trying to see who on a data extension was actually suppressed from a send.

In my mind, there should be an easy way to do this: set up something like "IS on data extension x" AND "IS on list/suppression list y."

There doesn't seem to be any way to do that though. Am I and the support staff member I was working with missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to check this after the email has been sent:

1. **Query against the _Sent dataview**
   *You query to see which emails are in your sendable DE, but not in the Sent Dataview*

   ```
   SELECT yourde.EmailAddress
   FROM YourSendableDE as yourde
   LEFT OUT JOIN _Sent as s
   ON yourde.EmailAddress = s.SubscriberKey
   ```
2. **Query against your send log DE** *(Requires you to have a Send Log DE)*
   *You can query directly against your send log, but this would need you to collect the job ID or send date to be able to match against*

   ```
   SELECT yourde.EmailAddress
   FROM YourSendableDE as yourde
   LEFT OUTER JOIN yoursendlogDE as sl
   ON yourde.EmailAddress = sl.EmailAddress
   AND sl.jobID = 123456
   ```

If you just want to collect unsubscribes and/or bounces, you can easily do this through queries, measures or filters - but it won't give you the full suppression list.